# Regex Expression in python

Tags: python, regex-group

I am trying to match the pattern in the given statement and print it as a dictionary. That pattern has four parts. When I test those parts individually then they are printed individually but when I combined them they give none. Kindly help me.

I tried the following code, but it does not work as expected.

```py
pattern= """
(?P<host>[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}) - (?P<user_name>[\w]*) (?P<time>\[.*?\]) (?P<Request>\".*?\")
 """

statement= """ 146.204.224.152 - feest6811 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700] "POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1" 
"""
item=re.match(pattern,statement,re.VERBOSE|re.IGNORECASE)
print(item.groupdict())
```

I want to print the following output.

```
host :146.204.224.152 , user_name: feest6811 , time:[21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700], Request: "POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1"
```

Comment: Can you please provide the question more clearly. Do you actually mean `"""` around the pattern and the test string? In python the `"""` can have different meanings.

Comment: You are using `re.VERBOSE` so you would have to be specific in the pattern to match spaces. You can omit the flags like this https://ideone.com/tYqD48

Comment: @Thefourthbird that's an answer, not a comment!

Comment: Its perfectly working now. Thank you for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This could be helpful:

```py
import re, json

regex = r"(?P<host>(?:\d{3}\.){3}\d{3})\s-\s(?P<user_name>\S+)\s\[(?P<date>.+?)\]\s\"(?P<request>.+?)\""

test_str = "146.204.224.152 - feest6811 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700] \"POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1\""

for m in re.finditer(regex, test_str):

    if m:
        print(m.groupdict())
        # as a string
        print(json.dumps(m.groupdict()))
    else:
        print("No match")
```

Should give output as:

```py
{'host': '146.204.224.152', 'user_name': 'feest6811', 'date': '21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700', 'request': 'POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1'}
```